# python delete files from google cloud storage that starts with

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

Using python I am able to delete files from bucket using `prefixes` also but in python code, `prefix means directory`.
I want to delete the files from GCP bucket which starts with `example`.

For example:

`example-2022-12-07`

`example-2022-12-08`

I followed this([Delete Files from Google Cloud Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555080/delete-files-from-google-cloud-storage)) but did not get the answer.

I am trying this, but not working:

```
    blobs = bucket.list_blobs()
    fileList = [file.name for file in blobs if 'example' in file.name ]
    print(fileList)
    for file in fileList:
        blob = blobs.blob(file)
        blob.delete()
        print(f"Blob {blob_name} deleted.")
```

Comment: what happens when you try to run the code?

Comment: get this `line 15, in deleter blob = blobs.blob(file) AttributeError: 'HTTPIterator' object has no attribute 'blob'`

Comment: that means `blobs` is not what you think it is. Have you checked the documentation of `bucket.list_blobs()`?

Comment: I shared my solution, can you have a look at it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code to delete files from the Google Cloud Storage by using the blob.delete method as suggested in the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/samples/storage-delete-file#code-sample).

Below is the example for what you are looking:

```
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
# list all objects in the directory
# Add prefix as parameter to bucket.list_blobs
blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix=?)
for blob in blobs: 
   blob.delete()
   print(f"Blob {blob_name} deleted.")`
```

You can check with this [thread1](https://www.skytowner.com/explore/removing_files_on_google_cloud_storage_using_python) and [thread2](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/samples/storage-list-files-with-prefix#storage_list_files_with_prefix-python).